# How to use flatMap in scala in order to group a set of "vals"

Tags: java, list, scala, flatmap

I am new to scala and was just creatting a few examples to understand it better. I can't seem to figure out this issue here- I create a List of Strings in my java program and use this list in my scala program. My scala code to read the list from the java class looks something like this.

```
  private val stringList : Seq[List] = x.getStringName //gets the list from my java program.
```

The stringList contains

```
   ["How", "Are", "You"].
```

I am trying to find a way to add these strings to values called a, b and c, so that they could be later passed on a arguments to another function.

```
 val values = stringList.flatMap{
   case x if (!stringList.isEmpty) =>

      val a = /*should get the first string How*/
      val b = /*should get the second string Are*/
      val c = /*should get the third string You*/

  case _ => None
 }

 getCompleteString(a,b,c);
```

But this does not work. I tgives me an error saying

```
 "type mismatch; found : Unit required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]"
```

I am not use why this happens. Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

I am sorry if the code looks dirty, but I am a beginner and still trying to understand the language. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your `stringList ` has type `Seq[List]`? Shouldn't it be `List[String]` or `Seq[String]` or whatever? You can remove the type and see what your IDE tells you about the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it:

```
val a = stringList(0)
val b = stringList(1)
val c = stringList(2)

val (a, b, c) = stringList match {
  case first :: second :: third :: _ => (first, second, third)
  case _ => ("default for a", "default for b", "default for c") // default case..
}
```

The first approach is Java-ish, by index, but you have to check if the elements are there, e.g. not-null or whatever.

The second one is using tuples, where you assign multiple values at once. If the list has at least 3 elements(first case statement), then they will be assigned to (a,b,c) tuple, and then you can use a,b,c... If the list has less than 3 elements, default values will be used(0,0,0).

I am sure that there are more ways to achieve this in Scala.

Comment: Hey @insan-e thank you for that. In case instead of using String I use a list of Objects, then how do I do the same thing? Could you be kind enough to suggest something on this too?

Comment: It should be the same for any type of List, since it is generic, List[T]. :)

Comment: The return type from all case statements MUST be the same, in order to assign it to the tuple3, for example.